# Issue while fetching data from nested json

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to fetch data from a nested json. Not able to understand the issue over here. Please ignore the fields that I am passing to ChildArticle class. I can sort that out.

URL for JSON - http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostshared/all-sections/email/30.json?api-key=31fa4521f6572a0c05ad6822ae109b72:2:72729901

Below is my code:

```
url = 'http://api.nytimes.com'

#Define the HTTP object
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

#If the api being scraped uses https, then set use_ssl to true.
http.use_ssl = false

#Define the request_url
#Make a GET request to the given url
request = '/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostshared/all-sections/email/30.json?api-key=31fa4521f6572a0c05ad6822ae109b72:2:72729901'
response = http.send_request('GET', request)

#Parse the response body
forecast = JSON.parse(response.body)
forecast["results"]["result"].each do |item|

    date = Date.parse(item["published_date"].to_s)
    if (@start <= date) && (@end >= date)
        article = News::ChildArticle.new(author: item["author"], title: item["title"], summary: item["abstract"],
                                         images: item["images"],source: item["url"], date: item["published_date"],
                                         guid: item["guid"], link: item["link"], section: item["section"], 
                                         item_type: item["item_type"], updated_date: item["updated_date"], 
                                         created_date: item["created_date"], 
                                         material_type_facet: item["material_type_facet"])

        @articles.concat([article])
    end
end
```

I get below error -

> `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) at`forecast["results"]["result"].each do |item|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `forecast['results']` is simply an array, not a hash.

Take a look at this slightly modified script. Give it a run in your terminal, and check out its output.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'JSON'

url = 'http://api.nytimes.com'

uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = false

request = '/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostshared/all-sections/email/30.json?api-key=31fa4521f6572a0c05ad6822ae109b72:2:72729901'
response = http.send_request('GET', request)

forecast = JSON.parse(response.body)

forecast["results"].each.with_index do |item, i|
  puts "Item #{i}:"
  puts '--'

  item.each do |k, v|
    puts "#{k}: #{v}"
  end

  puts '----'
end
```

---

Also, you may want to inspect the JSON structure of the API return from that [URL](http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostshared/all-sections/email/30.json?api-key=31fa4521f6572a0c05ad6822ae109b72:2:72729901). If you go to that URL, open your [JavaScript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), and paste in

```
JSON.parse(document.body.textContent)
```

you can inspect the JSON structure very easily.

Another option would be downloading the response to a JSON file, and inspecting it in your editor. You'll need a JSON prettifier though.

```
File.open('response.json', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(response.body)
end
```